# Simulate network latency with Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, networking, servlets

Is it possible to configure Apache Tomcat to simulate network latency that a client would normally have when requesting data from server for requests over localhost?  I'm trying to test how the front end of a Java Servlet application will respond to requests that have slow response times.

I know I could go in and add `Thread.sleep(100)` to all of my Servlet Java source files, but I'd rather have a solution that can be configured in Tomcat rather than in my actual application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simulate network latency by using a proxy on your localhost which introduces latency, bandwidth restrictions, and even drop packets.

DonsProxy will do the job.  [Here's](http://chrisdegiere.com/2010/10/19/simulating-high-latency-low-bandwidth-connections/) a good article describing how to configure it to simulate a user on a poor network.

Comment: Dead link. Thats why you should always try to include solution, not paste links.

Comment: Here's the archive.org copy of the page. https://web.archive.org/web/20140313002751/http://chrisdegiere.com:80/2010/10/19/simulating-high-latency-low-bandwidth-connections/ good point though

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a [servlet filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) and have it intercept all requests.  In each of the request you would be doing this Thread.sleep or something else.  All requests to your servlets will be delayed.

Comment: This isn't really configurable in Tomcat though.  Or am I missing something?  The test application and the deployed application would have different web.xml files, wouldn't they?

Answer (score 1):

This is easily feasible in Tomcat by creating a valve.

Create a class that extends the ValveBase class from tomcat.

The code inside should be something like that:

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void invoke(final Request request, final Response response) 
                   throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (randomDelay != 0) {
        long delay = minDelay + randomizer.nextInt(randomDelay);
        try {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("sleeping for " + delay + " ms");
            }
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("someone wake me up : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    // let's continue !
    getNext().invoke(request, response);
}
```

Compile it in a jar you'll drop in the tomcat lib directory (usually {catalina.home}/lib).

Finally add the valve declaration in you server.xml:

```
<Server ...>
  <Service name="Catalina">
   <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
     (...)
     <Host name="localhost" ...>
       <Valve className="tools.tomcat.RandomDelayValve" />
```

HIH